# Rotating keypoints numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy

I have some sample images of cats where the keypoints are marked on the cat face. Here is a sample:

[image: Original image]

This is a 224x224 image and the keypoints are numpy arrays and the coordinates are as follows:

```
x: array([156.625  , 166.25   , 163.625  , 145.90625, 148.3125 , 154.875  ,
       164.71875, 172.375  , 168.65625], dtype=float32)
y: array([67.690506, 67.690506, 81.09781 , 58.861313, 41.20292 , 53.629196,
       53.629196, 43.49197 , 59.84234 ], dtype=float32)
```

The keypoints when plotted on original image looks like this

[image: Original image with keypoints plotted]

Now, I want to do an interesting thing. I want to flip the image horizontally and map the keypoints to the transformed image. I can flip the using `cv2.flip(img,1)` to flip the image but I am not getting how to transform the points accordingly. How can I do that in `numpy` or `scipy`?

Comment: AFAIK the flip does height-point.y and leaves the x the same... shouldn't that do it? if you flip also vertically do width-point.x too

Comment: These keypoints are plottedd as scatter points. They are not a part of the original image. They are provided separately

Comment: but they match the original image right? i mean they are exactly in the cat's face.... you can use the height of the image to do the same trick.

Comment: Yeah but I don't know how to do that. That's exactly what I am asking. How should I transform the coordinates now?

Comment: you can only flip them if you know the min and max coordinates in y (AKA height)

Comment: Can someone explain why it is put on hold? I have given almost every bit of information, if there was need of anything else, a comment would have suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to mirror your points around the vertical axis of your image, so that your new keypoints will have the following coordinates:

```
y_flip = y
x_flip = cv2.shape[1] - 1 - x
```

You just need to change the `x` coordinate, so that it goes "from right to left" instead of "from left to right". The -1 is to take into account pyhton indexing rules.